# Does perf reset counter after every sample?

Tags: profiling, perf

In Collecting Samples sections of the perf documentation, we can specify the sampling rate using -F option. According to my understanding, if -F 250 is used, perf will sample the counters 250 times per second on average. Does this mean that after sampling the counter, does that counter get reset? For example, consider two samples below(assume these are the only samples generated for the function f1)

1. sample S1 reporting c1 cycles in function f1
2. sample S2 reporting c2 cycles in function f1

Suppose I have to calculate approximately how many cycles are spent in all calls of function f1(assume in the application above there is only one call to f1). Is it right to say the answer is c1 + c2(This is true if the counters are reset after every sample)?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you're using other options or writing to the perf control pipe file-descriptor, a `cycles` event just reports where execution was when it triggered.  It doesn't tell you what the CPU was doing in the cycles before.  If execution spends a lot of cycles with the program counter inside `f1`, then you're statistically more likely to sample an event there, but that doesn't mean all the counted cycles were inside that function.  (Unless you know `f1` has a very long-running loop and execution never left between samples.)

Comment: Of course, out-of-order exec is a complication for counting cycles; the CPU usually has hundreds of instructions in flight at various stages of the pipeline, some buffered in the front-end, some already executed just sitting in the ROB waiting to retire (which can't happen until all older instructions are ready to retire).  An interrupt will usually roll back to retirement state, so often the instruction after one that was slow.  (Intel CPUs I think like to wait for the last in-progress instruction, presumably to ensure forward progress with constant interrupts.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the insight! My idea was if this was true to calculate the value of each performance counter by going through 1(or more) passes through perf report samples. After your explanation, I don't think it is possible. I will have to access performance counters directly(through msr) if nothing else works. If it is not too much to ask, can you tell me if any tool would allow me to access the total count of a HW register(cycle, cache misses, for example) for each function in a program?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool; it wouldn't be possible without *huge* measurement overhead to sample and record the count before/after each function, including pretty short functions if they couldn't inline.  That's why `perf record` works by statistical sampling, looking at where the program counter happened to be when the counter for an event passed a threshold and wrapped.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks again for the answer. It helps me in deciding on the next step.